# Is there another way of making a column layout better for responsiveness?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I made a codesandbox that shows my current status. If you change the column-count to three, a lot of information gets lost because it won't scroll.

I have tried using grid and flexbox but it always goes from left to right instead of top to bottom.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-rgb-pr0h7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be fixed if you add an `overflow: auto` on line `119` 

Your code with the overflow:

```
const Content = styled.div`
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
  background: hsla(0deg, 50%, 100%, 1);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
  z-index: 120;
  overflow: auto;
`;
```